# creating a salesforce validation rule for one of the object

Tags: salesforce

I am creating a salesforce validation rule for one of the object which is related to Date field.

```
OR((Delivery_Date_From__c < TODAY()+1), (Placement_Date_From__c < TODAY()+1), true, false)
```

This gives me a validation, but when i remove the `true`, `false` from the validation formula, it doesn't give me any validation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tested with the current day or days in the past? By using today + 1 you are always comparing the date against tomorrow ... always.

Comment: My scenario is to not allow the user to edit the dates in past, if i just use Today without +1 its the same case.
Can this be achieved using ISCHANGED function?

Answer (score 0):

By adding `true` to the OR function you are forcing it to *always* return true. Validation Rules cause an error when they return `true`, thus users will never be able to save a record. Instead try this:

```
OR(
 AND(ISCHANGED(Delivery_Date_From__c),  Delivery_Date_From__c <= TODAY()),
 AND(ISCHANGED(Placement_Date_From__c), Placement_Date_From__c <= TODAY())
)
```

This way the comparison only happens if the date is actually being edited, and if the date is before or equal to today it will return true, causing validation to throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Including the `true` parameter in an `OR` logic, will always trigger your validation rule.

Please give this a try.

```
OR(
    Delivery_Date_From__c < (TODAY()+1),
    Placement_Date_From__c < (TODAY()+1)
)
```